# How do I format the NUMBER function (Oracle SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to recreate a query similar to this one:

```
DECLARE
  bonus   NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
  SELECT salary * 0.10 INTO bonus
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = 100;
END;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bonus = ' || TO_CHAR(bonus));
```

But I don't understand the syntax for NUMBER. What is the purpose of the 2 in (8,2)? Does this round the result to two decimal places? I haven't seen this syntax when dealing with VARCHAR2 or similar variables.

Comment: first number (8) is precision, second number (2) is scale. This means it can store 8 *total* digits, 2 of which are after the decimal point, which gives you 6 digits to the left of the decimal and 2 to the right. If you try to insert a number with more than 6 digits left of the decimal it will error. If you insert a number with more than 2 digits right of the decimal it will simply round it. Numbers with scales of 2 are usually dollar amounts (cents being the reason for 2 digits after the decimal)

Comment: Perhaps you should refer to the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608)?

Answer (score 1):

So, when having a number variable in PL/SQL, it's best not to constrain it to something like that NUMBER(8,2), for, in case you happen to have larger values selected into that variable, that will lead to an exception. Better just declare them NUMBER. The format when converting to character is a different thing. Thus, you may use: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bonus = ' || TO_CHAR(bonus,'999990.00'));
RTM on to_char and format masks.
Or, even better, when selecting into some variable(s) in PL/SQL, use %type and %rowtype (RTM on those too), so as to avoid surprises in case the table(s) you select from are altered and the data will no longer fit into those variables.

Comment: I think it would be better to just use DECLARE bonus employees.salary%type;